# $f$ has a vertical asymptote, $f'$ is locally integrable: is it possible?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to find a differentiable function $f:\,]0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

- $f(t)\to-\infty$ as $t\to0+$
- $f(1)=0$
- $f'\in L^1[0,1]$

?

I'm trying do build an example, but all my attempts failed because the first and the third condition does not seem to be compatible.

For example I tryed with $f(t)=\log t$, $f(t)=1-\frac{1}{t}$, $f(t)=1-\frac{1}{t^2}$, $f(t)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$, $f(t)=\log\log(1+t)-\log2$ ...

Comment: If $f$ is supposed to be the integral of its derivative, then $$\int_0^1 f'(t)\,dt = f(1) - \lim_{s\searrow 0} f(s) = +\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you! Then one should look for a function which is differentiable on $]0,1]$, but whose derivative is not continuous on $]0,1]$...